# T-SQL count of unique records by each month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get the count by which our customer base grew each month.

Eg. "Josh","Tim" and "Dustin" has used the service in January, so for January the number of new unique customers would be 3.

In February the "Josh","Tim" and "Eve" would use the service. As "Josh" and "Tim" has used the service before, the number of new unique customers would be 1.

And so on....

I wanted to use EXCEPT statement, but obviously this is not getting the right results.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Name) as NewUniqueCustomers, convert(varchar(7), RegDate, 126)
FROM T
GROUP BY convert(varchar(7), RegDate, 126)
EXCEPT 

--This should excludie all customers which was included previously
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Name)as NewUniqueCustomers, convert(varchar(7), RegDate, 126)
FROM T 
WHERE convert(varchar(7), DATEADD(month,-1,RegDate) , 126)

GROUP BY convert(varchar(7), RegDate, 126)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/73621

Comment: Just a note. Instead of converting dates to strings, use `cast(RegDate as Date)`. The conversion prevents the server from using indexes and results in very bad performance.

Comment: I would like them to be grouped by YEAR-MONTH. I am just struggling to find a way how to exclude names that were included in previous month

Comment: some code performing the insert of users? if thats the case why not in insert check if user already exist and add a flag that it already exist or not,
counting is much easier you can add condition to count only those users you were tagged as new

Comment: Sorry, my question might have been a bit misleading. Those are customers (i do have both surname name title in live system). And those could use service multiple times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your sqlfiddle this should do it.

```
with SortedData as
(
    select *
        , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Name order by RegDate) as RowNum
    from t
)

select dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, RegDate), 0) 
    , COUNT(Name)
from SortedData sd
where sd.RowNum = 1
group by dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, RegDate), 0)
```

--EDIT--

Given your comment about needing to pull from two tables with a union why not something like this?

```
with SortedData as
(
    select *
        , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Name order by RegDate) as RowNum
    from 
    (
        SELECT * FROM ProductionTable 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT * FROM Archive.dbo.T
    )
    x
)
```

Comment: This works perfectly, however in live system I need to UNION ALL two tables (Live and archive database). I usually do sub-query like FROM( SELECT * FROM T UNION ALL SELECT * FROM Archive.dbo.T) but i am getting error on this sub-query . Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks. I completely forgot that i need to alias table after the subquery.